# Codename one: Update status locked

Tags: codenameone

I have already gone through the process of sending an IOS debug build and opening on my IPHONE in an app in codename on.
I did the same steps on another app, but there is an error log that stops me from opening the file in codename one server. I am sending screenshots of the error log and the update lock when pressing "update project libs" error.

[image]

EDIT:

New error log file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/d2u50q5blki0f32/error%20%2817%29.txt?dl=0

Comment: We need the error log file itself, not a screenshot of it and seriously? Notepad?
You can delete the lock file if it's stuck there. That's why the error message gives the path to it.

Comment: Delete lock file, fixed. However, still the same error after build.

Comment: What's the error after build?

Comment: No error after build. Only error in codename server. With the log file as shown in the error file link. My other project works normally.

Comment: Error file link: https://ufile.io/7udf4

Comment: Your certificate doesn't match your provisioning profile. Did you use the certificate wizard? Did you revoke/regenerate? Is your path to the certificate/provisioning correct?

Comment: Yes. I passed that, but there is a new error. If i do not solve it through codename one, I will return here or in a new post.

Comment: new error link:
https://cloud.codenameone.com/build/getData?m=result&i=0a327302-e3c0-4057-875d-beb05211f819&b=f9cb68b9-8dcd-4a70-9a22-3059340cf964&n=error.txt

Comment: The error link is expired by now

Comment: https://cloud.codenameone.com/build/getData?m=result&i=1e265a30-f4f8-46df-9408-6422376cafdc&b=ca421c77-ed5d-436f-a362-bd73e7a6b21d&n=error.txt

Comment: This one is also expired, I suggest using a dropbox link if you keep building

Comment: Sorry.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d2u50q5blki0f32/error%20%2817%29.txt?dl=0

Comment: I reset all the build hints to work. Thank you.